# Auto fields / placeholders in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use Outlook 2016 to write a lot of emails.

I am tired of typing always the first name or the last name of a person (Dear $firstname, Dear Mr./Mrs $lastname).

Word offers Fields as placeholders to use some meta data. 
Is there a similar option in Outlook 2016?

Comment: Isn't the Mail Merge option from Word a good option for your needs?

Comment: No I want to answer emails using Outlook and not Word :)

Comment: You'll need to either write VBA macro for this or use third-party addin.